# Powershell Script to pass the results of multiple Get-SMB requests in to a csv file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

New to powershell, where am i going wrong here?
any assistance would be awesome.

Powershell Script to pass the results of multiple Get-SMB requests in to a csv file.

will execute with no errors but the csv is empty.

```
$OutArray= @()

$SmbCommands = @(
$SmbInfo1 = Get-SmbClientConfiguration
$SmbInfo2 = Get-SmbMapping
$SmbInfo3 = Get-SmbMultichannelConstraint
$SmbInfo4 = Get-SmbServerConfiguration
$SmbInfo5 = Get-SmbShare
)

# For Each
foreach ($i in $SmbCommands)
    {
        # Construct object
        $myobj = "" | Select "SmbInfo1", "$SmbInfo2", "$SmbInfo3", "$SmbInfo4", "$SmbInfo5"
        #$myobj = "" | Select "SmbInfo1", "$SmbInfo2", "$SmbInfo3", "$SmbInfo4", "$SmbInfo5" #im trying to pass ^^^ those commands in to the object creator <<<<<

        # Fill the object
        $myobj.SmbInfo1 = $SmbInfo1
        $myobj.SmbInfo2 = $SmbInfo2
        $myobj.SmbInfo3 = $SmbInfo3
        $myobj.SmbInfo4 = $SmbInfo4
        $myobj.SmbInfo5 = $SmbInfo5

        # Add the object to the out-array
        $OutArray += $myobj

        # Wipe object
        $myobj = $null
    }

# After the loop, exports the array to CSV
$OutArray | export-csv "C:\Temp\SMBInfo.csv"
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the resulting CSV file to look like? The output objects from these commands have different property sets, so you'll either end up with rows where the majority of the columns are empty, or you'll lose data

Comment: no idea mate as i havent got it to work yet, id address the format later, just want the results out in any form

Comment: id probably just out put to txt in the end

Comment: How about a format that actually supports hierarchical data, like JSON? `$OutArray |ConvertTo-Json |Set-Content output.json`

Comment: $OutArray | ConvertTo-Json "C:\Temp\SMBInfo.json" <----- like that?

Comment: tbh all i want to achieve is the results from those requests in a txt file

Comment: JSON is text, so I guess that solves it :-)

Comment: what does it solve?

Comment: `$OutArray |ConvertTo-Json |Set-Content output.json` writes the information you've collected to a text file - isn't that the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: but there is nothing being passed to said file, so the file is empty, still in the same boat as before :) cheers tho, ill look in to json as output when i get the rest of it to work :D

Answer (score 0):

The output array is empty because your `$SmbCommands` array is empty, since assignment statements (like `$SmbInfo1 = Get-SmbClientConfiguration`) do not output anything in PowerShell by default.

Instead, do this:

```
# Create an object that holds all the queried information (like you were trying to do with $myObj)
$smbInfo = [pscustomobject]@{
  SmbInfo1 = Get-SmbClientConfiguration
  SmbInfo2 = Get-SmbMapping
  SmbInfo3 = Get-SmbMultichannelConstraint
  SmbInfo4 = Get-SmbServerConfiguration
  SmbInfo5 = Get-SmbShare
}

# Convert the object hierarchy to JSON
$JSON = $smbInfo |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

# Write output to disk  
$JSON |Set-Content output.json
```